# Unicorn: javascript assets ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH in Rails 3.2.19

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, unicorn, cloud9-ide

I'm using *Rails 3.2.19* with *Unicorn 4.8.3* in *development* on Cloud9 and it suddenly stopped to serve well some javascript files (e.g.: jquery/bootstrap).

The error in Chrome console for those files is:

**Failed to load resource net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH**

I have this configuration in *config/application.rb*:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

And this in my *config/environments/development.rb*:

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is an extreme odd bug on Cloud9 in which the internal C9 Proxy truncates the HTTP Response randomly. I will post again in the future when the C9 bug is fixed.